# Send data from web to a local server

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am working on a home automation hub -- a Raspberry Pi running **locally** that displays weather info, controls my lights, etc. It is "networked" (and I use that term loosely) to a website via a shared MongoDB. Both the site and the hub are running Node.js/Express servers.

Essentially, I am looking to be able to enter text into a field on my website and then display it on my hub.

I'm struggling to figure out how to pass data between them. I can think of a couple ways that *might* get it done, but the only way I know I could get working is to implement some sort of Mongo watcher/listener to watch for changes on a specific collection. Essentially, you enter the text into the site, that updates the document in Mongo, the watcher informs the locally-running hub, which then fetches and displays the new content.

This seems hacky. Is there a better way? Is this something socket.io could manage? Maybe I'm overthinking it? Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Socket.io, WebSocket or TCP socket to connect the two servers together and communicate that way. Or you can use a queue system like ZeroMQ or RabbitMQ and communicate that way. Or you can even make an HTTP request from one server to the other one every time you want it to grab new data - or you could even sent that data right in the request.

It would be much easier if you used Redis that supports pub/sub, see:

- https://redis.io/topics/pubsub

or CouchDB that supports the changes feed:

- http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/api/database/changes.html

or RethinkDB that supports changefeeds:

- https://rethinkdb.com/docs/changefeeds/javascript/

I don't think Mongo supports anything like that.

Comment: I didn't think I could use a standard HTTP request from web to a localhost port/route. Am I wrong about that? Regardless, thank you for these options. Looking forward to exploring all of these!